# Ember helper to capitalize first letter on input

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to create an Ember helper that when a user enters first and last name on input field it  will capitalize the first letter of both names.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
 return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1, 0);

}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(capitalizeFirstLetter);
```

The above code capitalize every character of first and last name and only on output. It does not dynamically capitalize when user is typing. eg. feeling out the form with

```
<input value=firstName>john
<input value=lastName> smith
```

On keyup it should automatically display John Smith under each field.

Comment: Can't you just use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/AbxVx/ or is ember mandatory?

Comment: @Fernanda Silva, Why do you need a helper to solve your problem? The much simpler solution would be to use {{input type="text" value=firstName key-up="<action_name>"}}. Define the action in your controller

Comment: Why not just use css for this?

Comment: @Kitler , Using css just capitalizes when displaying, It doesn't change the controller property.  @Fernanda Silva, You can extend `Ember.TextField` to observe `value` and update it as you want.

Comment: @AcidBurn why on earth would you want the property to be capitalised? It is a styling/presentation thing.

Comment: @Kitler Assumed that he wants so.